# How to display multiple images on user command?

Tags: c#, image, event-handling, paintevent

I need to be able to display a group of images after the user presses a menu on the Gui. I have been trying to use the following code.

```
 private void imagePalleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Files = this.MyImageCollection.ConvertFileNamesToList();
        foreach (string currtFile in Files)
        {
            Image newImage = Image.FromFile(currtFile);

            // Create rectangle for displaying image.
            Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 450, 150);

            // Draw image to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, destRect);
        }
```

I think this would work but I get the error:

'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics' and no extension method 'Graphics' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried replaceing EventHandler with PaintEventHandler, but then I get an error here:

```
this.imagePalleteToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.imagePalleteToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

Stating:

No overload for 'imagePalleteToolStripMenuItem_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I also tried changing that line to:

```
this.imagePalleteToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.imagePalleteToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

But this too gives an error stating:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'r

**Note:**My over all goal is to  invoke a dialog that will display all the images in thumbnail form. So if this is not the correct way to do so, please redirect me

Comment: Added all of the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the paint event with the click event. If you want something to happen when a user clicks a button, you put that in the click event.  What would you be painting to in a button click?

Instead, design a new form to show your images, on the button click event, gather your images, and give those images to your dialog. Let the dialog worry about displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you grabbed some sample code that was originally in an `OnPaint` event. You've added this to a totally different type of event, which does not pass you a `Graphics` object. You either need to put this code in the `OnPaint` event of whatever control you want this in, or try a completely different approach.

The correct solution depends on exactly how you want this to work (are you trying to updated something already on screen, show a new dialog, etc).